# C++ Algorithm to determine all possible join-orders

Tags: c++, database, graph

bI am currently doing some research in databases.

I need to find all possible join orders for a given join graph. The graph is implemented as a adjancence list.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM a, b, c, d WHERE a.x = b.x && b.y = c.y && b.z = d.z
```

gives us the following graph (edges):

```
(a,b)
(b,c)
(b,d)
```

and all possible join orders would be (x is the join operator):

```
((a x b) x c) x d
((a x b) x d) x c
(a x (b x c)) x d
(a x (b x d)) x c
a x ((b x c) x d)
a x ((b x d) x c)
```

My first idea was running kind of a PRIM algorithm for each vertex. Everytime, we could add different edges to connect a vertex, which is not part of the MST, to the MST, we found another join order. Does this approach work? Is there a simpler solution to get all possible join orders?

Moritz

Comment: The edge `(c,d)` is not in your graph -- `(b,d)` is.

Comment: If you're looking for all valid join orders, then you need to also consider orders in which you grow 2 or more separate components, and then join them together at the end.  E.g. if the last clause of the query was `c.z = d.z`, so that the graph was in fact `(a,b), (b,c), (c,d)` then you would also have the join order `(a x b) x (c x d)`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You are right. That makes the problem even worst.

Comment: I seem to recall from the PostgreSQL docs that planning an optimal join order (assuming you have costs for each edge) might be equivalent to the Steiner Minimal Tree problem, which is NP-complete.  In any case, there are a vast number of possibilities once you have more than a few possibilities, hence why they switch from evaluating every possible one to evolutionary heuristics.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I know that they use heuristics. But for my research it is necessary to evaluate all possibilities.

Comment: There's a distinct join order for every ordering of edges of every possible spanning tree.  If the graph is dense, it will have many spanning trees.  In the worst case it's a complete graph, with edges between every pair of vertices -- this will happen when the field being joined on is common to every join, e.g. for `a.x = b.x and b.x = c.x and c.x = d.x`.  In this case, for n tables there are n^(n-2) spanning trees by Cayley's formula, each of which has (n-1)! orders of edges.  So e.g. for 8 tables, there are 10569646080 join orders.

Comment: I only consider the join orders of explicit mentioned join-predicates. For your example, you assume that the database identifies that a can be joined with c and d, but there are no explicit join predicates for those joins. Moreover, I will (for now) assume that my join-graph is acyclic. Thus I get all join-orders by permuting the explicit join-predicates.

Comment: If you assume the join graph is acyclic then this simplifies things enormously.  And I now realise that there are fewer than (n-1)! join orders per spanning tree -- the (n-1)! number assumes that joining `a` and `b`, then `c` and `d`, and finally joining these 2 relations, is different than joining `c` and `d`, then `a` and `b`, when this is really the same order.  Not sure if it's possible to count the "real" orders with a closed-form expression, but it's easy enough to calculate with an O(2^n) DP that considers all subsets of tables.